# How to manage file paths dynamically in code?

Tags: path

So my supervisor (I am a working student) came up to me with the following task:

*"Please think of a solution how we can dynamically adapt the file paths in the code when there are changes."*

He also said he was thinking of an excel file with file pathes and if there is a change you just change it in the excel file and our codes adapt dynamically this change.
So every file path variable in our code then is just a reference to some excel cell this is doable with openpyxl for me I guess.

But I wanted to ask you guys how your corporation manages these problems and if there might be a more ellegant way to solve this.

Comment: There’s no way of helping without understanding what problem is being solved. Environment variables, command-line arguments, a database, config files, etc are all possible solutions.

Comment: There is no specific problem. In my company we heavily work with excel and our team just automate some stuff in python and our code relies on the folder structer within our company. This structure might change so my supervisor wants me to find a solution to manage these changes in our code. I hope this is understandable. :D